# JQuery.Validation -> SubmitHandler event with AjaxSubmit is not a function error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Hi I am trying to call my controller/action MVC in the submitHandler of the JQuery.Validation and it is not working in there, I could make it work creating the $ajax outside the event submitHandler in the cshtml in  there worked, but why here doesnt work? I receive a error: ajaxSubmit is not a function in firebug. why? Thanks

```
var form = $('.handlevalidation');
    var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
    var success = $('.alert-success', form);

    form.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "", // validate all fields including form hidden input
        messages: {
            'Employee.Username': { remote: "This Username was already taken." },
            'Employee.Barcode': { remote: "This Barcode is already in use." }
        },
        rules: {

            // ** RULES **
            'Employee.Username': {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 55,
                required: true,
                remote: { url: baseUrl + 'Employees/CheckDuplicatedUsername', type: "post", data: { username: function () { return $('#Employee_Username').val(); }, id: function () { return $('#Employee_Id').val(); } } }
            },

            'Employee.Password': { minlength: 3, maxlength: 55, required: false },
            'Employee.Barcode': {
                maxlength: 255,
                required: false,
                remote: { url: baseUrl + 'Employees/CheckDuplicatedBarcode', type: "post", data: { barcode: function () { return $('#Employee_Barcode').val(); }, id: function () { return $('#Employee_Id').val(); } } }
            },

            'Employee.FirstName': { minlength: 3, maxlength: 55, required: true },
            'Employee.LastName': { minlength: 3, maxlength: 55, required: false },
            'Employee.EmailAddress': { required: false, email: true },

            'Password': { required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 10 },
            'ConfirmPassword': { required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 10, equalTo: "#Password" }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit              
            success.hide();
            error.show();
            Metronic.scrollTo(error, -200);
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
        },

        success: function (label) {
            label
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set success class to the control group
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            success.show();
            error.hide();


            $form.ajaxSubmit({
                type: 'post',
                url: baseUrl + 'Employees/UpdatePassword',
                data: $form.serialize(),

                success: function (response) {

                    if (response == 'success') {

                        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
                        alert('Password changed successfully!');

                        $target.modal('hide');

                    } else {
                        error.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `form` outside `submitHandler` context is `$('.handlevalidation')` but, inside your function it will make reference to the parameter *(since it has the same name)*. I'll suggest to do `console.log(form)` and also  `console.log($form)` to see what you get. Can you please include the output in your question? Btw, will be good if next time you create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi, yes, I fixed that, but I am getting now a problem in the $form.ajaxsubmit, which is: ReferenceError: form is not defined

Comment: Try changing this: `submitHandler: function(form) {` to: `submitHandler: function(frm) {` *(notice that 'form' param was converted into 'frm')*. Now, inside `submitHandler` do a `console.log(form);` and after that `form.ajaxSubmit({ /* config here */ });` and see what happens, did it work?

Comment: It's hard to check what could be the source of the problem since `form` param from `submitHandler` must be there, that's an odd behavior. Is it possible to share your html?

Comment: Thanks, I fix it, it was variables problems, i used:
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl + 'Employees/UpdatePassword',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $(form).serialize(),

                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response) {

                            success.show();
                            $($(form).attr('data-target')).modal('hide');

                        } else {
                            error.show();
                        }
                    }
                });